France visa - how to prove personal links to the country of residence as a foreigner
I am a foreign worker in Canada. When preparing for the France business visa from Canada, it requires me to provide documents demonstrating the applicant’s personal links to the country of residence (e.g. copy of marriage certificate, family record book). I am not married, don't have any family nor properties here in Canada. Is there any other way for me to prove that I have the strong tie to Canada?

This question is similar to: How to prove that I will return back to my country of origin?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Good job? Integration on community? Family? etc. Note: if you are a Canadian things may be easier compared on other countries where wages are lower, unemployment is much higher and living condition may be lower, so more incentives not to return. (it is a balance to find probability you will not return back home)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Canadian citizens do not need a visa for short stays (the only kind of visa where ties to the country of residence are relevant). The OP already stated that they are not Canadian in this question (cf. title) and an earlier one

I think that by far the most common way to demonstrate ties to the country is to have a stable, well paid job (so pay slips + bank statements + work contract).

Think about what compelling reason(s) you have to leave France and go back to Canada and provide evidence to show that. Probably a stable job that gives you an income at least as good as the average annual salary in France, and requires your presence in Canada, ie is not remote working, would be ideal.
